# UITableview cell ignores constrains

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have set a fixed width for a UIButton inside of a cell, which is inside of a UITableView. When changing text programmatically in the UIButton,the UIButton is starting to resize. When I am changing text in the Storyboard, the UIButton's width stays the size I told him to be (not changing). Why does the UIButton is resizing when changing text programmatically? I do not want this to happen. Thanks.

00:00 is a UILabel, 100 + 1000 & 500 is the UIButton, which should have a fixed width.[image]
[image]

Code:

```
freeCoinsArray.append(freeCoinsClass(freeCoinsImage: "Coin", freeCoinsDescription: "Free coins", getFreeCoins: "100 + 1000", freeCoinsCountdown: "00:00"))
```

Cell for row at function:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! FreeCoinsTableViewCell

        cell.imageForFreeCoins.image = UIImage(named: freeCoinsArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].freeCoinsImage!)
        cell.descriptionFreeCoins.text = freeCoinsArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].freeCoinsDescription
        cell.getFreeCoinsButton.setTitle(freeCoinsArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].getFreeCoins, for: .normal)
        cell.countDown.text = freeCoinsArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].freeCoinsCountdown

        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        return cell
```

However I now see that the UITableView is ignoring more constrains. I also have a image view with a proportional height of 0.3 of the row, but it is scaled to 1.0 of the row's height. see:

How it should be:
[image]

How it is:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your question/add some of your code etc.

Comment: Yes I added some more code and pictures.

Comment: You are sure your constraints are set properly? Try the "suggested constraints" feature or declare things like the width in code.